# MYSQL data missing on data display

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter framework to save and fetch data from a MYSQL database. I do have a problem like this.

This happens once in a while only.

The process is save some data of a table and fetch them and display with a page refresh. Everything goes well, all the data are saved to the database. But once in a while, when the page refreshes and loads the data, some data are not displaying and comes with an empty data as follows.

**result: ""**

But data is in the database.

When I reloads again, the missing data is displayed correctly. This happens to me on the local server and the production hosting. But not every time, not the same data. The missing data element comes empty to the page. Without changing anything, if I reload the page data, everything works fine. What can be the reason for this?

```
    $.ajax({
           
       url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/Lab/resulting'); ?>",
       data:{bill_no:bill_no},
       method:"GET",
       dataType:"JSON",
       
       success:function(data){
       
         var result_area ="";
         for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
         { 
   
           var element_id = data[count].element_id;      
           var ct = 'select'+count+'';
           var bt = count;
         var result = 'result'+count+''
         
 /*
           $('#data_table_one tbody').append(
                 '<tr>'+
               
              
                 '<td style=" vertical-align: middle;white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">'+(count+1)+'</td>'+
                 '<td id="reult_id'+count+'" style="display:none" name="reult_name'+count+'">'+data[count].billing_element_result_id+'</td>'+
                 '<td id="bill_no'+count+'" style=" vertical-align: middle;white-space: nowrap;text-align: center;">'+data[count].bill_no+'</td>'+
                 '<td style="display:none">'+data[count].processor_id+'</td>'+
                 '<td style=" vertical-align: middle;">'+data[count].test_processor_display_name+'</td>'+
               
                 '<td style=" vertical-align: middle;white-space: nowrap;">'+data[count].test_details+'</td>'+
              
     
                 '<td  id="result'+count+'" style=" vertical-align: middle;white-space: pre;text-align: center;">'+data[count].result+'</td>'+
                
                 '<td id="'+count+'" class="result_enter_cell" contenteditable=true style=" vertical-align: middle;white-space: pre;text-align: center;"><select class="form-control input-sm text-left " id="select'+count+'" style="display:none"></select></td>'+
                
                    (data[count].by_calculation ==1 ?
                  '<td></td>' : 
                  '<td id="button1'+count+'" style=" vertical-align: middle;white-space: nowrap;text-align: center;"><button type="button" name="add_btn" id="add_result'+count+'" class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn_set_result btn-sm">Set Result</td>'
                  )+           
                
                
                   
                 
 
 
                 '</tr>'
               
                 );
```

Controller returns fetched data as json_encode

Comment: Open the developer console in your browser and check the Networking tab for requests, making sure to have the tab open *before* you encounter this error. Something in the data is probably causing an error in your PHP script, either returning just an error or invalid JSON, thus the javascript fails to parse the response and can't display anything. Find the request in the Networking tab, and check the response body, and you'll probably find an error message that will help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: @404NotFound there is no error in console. the loosing response is having an empty resonse as i mentioned above.

Comment: furthermore, this doesn't happen always. Once in a while only. if the page is reloaded, everything works fine

Comment: I just added a small delay for the refresh and fetch. The problem didn't arrive again. Thanks all for the help.